# Swap two characters in bash with tr or similar

Tags: bash, replace, tr

I'm doing a bash script and I have a problem. I would like to change the position of two characters in a string.

My input is the following:

```
"aaaaa_eeeee"
```

The desired output is:

```
"eeeee_aaaaa"
```

I don't want to invert the string or anything else like that, what I need is to replace the character "a" by the "e" and the "e" by the "a". I have tried to make a `echo "aaaaa_eeeee" | tr "a" "e` . The first replacement is simple but the second one I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can give multiple original and replacement characters to `tr`. Each character in the original string is replaced with the corresponding replacement character.

```
echo "aaaaa_eeeee" | tr "ae" "ea"
```

Answer (score 2):

### Pass Translation Sets as Arguments

To make the substitutions work in a single logical pass, you need to pass multiple characters to the *tr* utility. The man page for the BSD version of tr describes the use of translation sets as follows:

> [T]he characters in *string1* are translated into the characters in *string2* where the first character in *string1* is translated into the first character in *string2* and so on. If *string1* is longer than *string2*, the last character found in *string2* is duplicated until *string1* is exhausted.

For example:

```sh
$ tr "ae" "ea" <<< "aaaaa_eeeee"
eeeee_aaaaa
```

This maps `a => e` and `e => a` in a single logical pass, avoiding the issues that would result in trying to map the replacements sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for rev:

```
echo "aaaaa_eeeee"|rev
eeeee_aaaaa
```